# After updating from 2.4.4 to 2.4.6, price field showing validation error

Tags: magento2, price, upgrade, validation, magento2.4.6

I just recently updated to 2.4.6, and while I was using 2.4.4 this problem never occurred. After editing/adding a price to a product, and I click out of focus of the field, I get this error:

> Please enter a number 0 or greater, without comma in this field.

Even though I am not adding a comma, and the number is greater than 0. When I input a number, it seems fine. It's when I leave the field and a comma is auto-generated for me, this error pops up.

This is a custom module price field that's been created inside: app/code/Vendor/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/MsrpNew.php

I feel like this has nothing to do with the validation and rather it's some underlying issue from the update, since in 2.4.4 the same validation & comma's get added automatically after leaving the field, and I never had this issue...

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.